# Calculating the annualized average returns with resample('Y') and without

Tags: python

I'm trying to calc the annualized return of Amazon stock and can't figure out the main difference between the following approaches

`df = pdr.get_data_yahoo('amzn',datetime(2015, 1, 1),datetime(2019, 12, 31))['Adj Close']`

1)`df.pct_change()).mean()*252`

Result = 0,400

2)`df.resample('Y').last().pct_change().mean()`

Result = 0,472

Why there is a difference about 7% ?

Comment: Before asking general question such as this, take the time to read the doc for the functions.  If you did so, you would see that in your first example you are computing the percentage change from the immediately previous row  and then finding the mean.  In the second case, resample() is a time-based groupby, followed by a reduction method on each of its groups after which you are finding the mean of the values.

Comment: thx for your feedback

Answer (score 2):

After reading the doc for the functions, I'd like go through an example of resampling time series data for a better understanding.

With resample method the price column of the DataFrame is grouped by a certain time span, in this case the **'Y'** indicates a resampling by year and with **last()** we get the price value at the end of each year.

```
data.resample('Y').last()
```

Output: [1. Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgGPR.png)

Next, with **pct_change()** we calculate the percentage change between the values for each row and the previous rows which are the price values at the end of each year that we got before.

```
data.resample('Y').last().pct_change()
```

Output: [2. Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwAOC.png)

Now, in the final step we calculate the mean percentage change during the entire time period by using the **mean()** method

```
data.resample('Y').last().pct_change().mean()
```

Output: [3. Step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZ0le.png)

like @itprorh66 already wrote, the main difference between the two approaches is just about when the mean of the values is calculated.

Comment: Great explanation